# Are there any "Both Rising Edge and Falling Edge Triggered" Shift Register?

Tags: multiplexer, multiplier, logisim, sequential-logic

I was designing this circuit in Logisim-evolution. In the book, it is mentioned that an n-bit multiplier would require n-clock cycles to work. I think this will be possible only when we have the shift register load during its rising edge, and make the shift operation during its falling edge. But, Shift Registers in Logisim/Logisim-evolution are either Negative Edge or Positive Edged triggered. This would cause the operation to complete in 2n clock cycles. Can we have a circuit which can do both?

One approach I thought of Having a MUX which would select either my clock or its negation, and the switch happens when the original clock has passed one-fourth of its cycle. This would require a clock which would be 90 degrees phase shifted than the original clock and we would use this as the select bit. But, this method seems complicated. Can we have a simpler approach in Logisim/Logisim-evolution?
[image: Sequencial Binary Multiplier Circuit]

Comment: Why not double the clock rate?

Comment: Are you just asking about creating and/or using a DETFF-based shift register? If so, these are all the rage today for low-power purposes. Google it.

Comment: A lot of high-performance microprocessors use multiple clock phases. I'm not familiar with modern stuff, so I'm not sure if it's still the case, but I know there were MPUs in the past that required you to give them two or four clocks with specific relationships between them. (look up "four-phase logic")

Comment: @jonk Is this circuit usable for a DETFF-based register? https://d3i71xaburhd42.cloudfront.net/a8cc569f4c1b8f5f51492d76eee6d0f8386ddd5e/2-Figure1-1.png . Do we have this on Logisim, or we have to design this from scratch?

Comment: @Andyaka This is another way I had thought of.

Comment: @VedantaMohapatra I honestly don't know about Logisim, but I doubt it is there. It's probably not in Neemann's Digital, either. Simulation I've read about uses Spectre.

Comment: The advantages of using both clock edges are tiny compared to the disadvantages and design problems it causes. Feeding one edge-clocked block from another now becomes very complicated to plan. That's why almost all logic circuits you'll design with will use a single clock edge, nearly always the positive edge. There's exceptions and so on, and I could go back to the 68000 MPU's bus interface, but the vast majority of cases don't. Just use a higher frequency clock with positive edge-clocked logic.

Comment: This really depends on logic family and clock speed.  Slower clocks would allow setup and hold times to be met, so positive and negative transitions work.  Faster clock, and less time for propagation and more problems.  Better to double clock rate.

Comment: It's possible to use an XOR gate with a delay on one input to create a pulse on both high and low clock transitions, effectively doubling clock rate, or implementing a shift register that operates on both transitions. I'm not sure this is what you need, as I am unfamiliar with Logisim. https://www.multisim.com/content/P8rjwzmNqC7G46Ew6jtyzG/coincidence-gate-clockfrequency-doubler/

Comment: What makes you think that you need both edges? The circuit you show does not seem to request that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Disclaimer:** This is not an answer to the title of the question, and the solution you want to realize. However, since you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I provide a solution for your underlying problem X. Other answers might suggest solutions for your idea Y.*

You don't need both edges or a doubled clock, since you can do the storing of the sum and the shifting of the result in one clock.

You can look at a shift register as a loadable register that gets its output fed back, but shifted by one. This is a right shifting register:

[image]

If you wire the bits accordingly, you achieve storing and shifting in one step.

This is my solution for a 4 by 4 multiplier, in the final state after multiplying 5 by 6. The result is shown in hex, 0x1E = 30. It needed one clock to load the multiplicand and multiplier, and 4 clocks to multiply.

[image]

Comment: Great answer; thanks for this.

Comment: Commonly you accept the answer that fits you best. It's the recommended way to say "Thank you"... ;-) You might want to take the [tour] to learn more about this site.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a direct answer for you in terms of Logisim, but I can hopefully shed some light as to why other solutions, such as doubling your clock rate, are generally easier to implement.

What you're talking about here is essentially Double Data Rate (DDR) transfers, where your data signal is sampled on both the rising and falling edges of the clock. This is also referred to as "double pumping".

The primary benefit of using DDR is that your data signals change state at the same rate as your clock signal does:

[image: Timing diagram showing the difference between SDR and DDR transition rates]

However, this property is not universally beneficial.

First, it is critical to realise that clock rate and signal frequency are not the same. A 1kHz clock with a 1ns rise/fall time (defined as the time it takes to transition between the 10-90% voltage levels) has a signal bandwidth of roughly 350MHz during the transitions. A 10MHz clock with the same rise/fall time *also* has a signal bandwidth of roughly 350MHz at the transitions. The only difference between those those 1kHz and 10MHz clock signals is how much time they spend at DC between the transitions.

The generally accepted rule of thumb is as follows:

$$BW = \frac {0.35} {T_r}$$

Where \$BW\$ is the signal bandwidth in GHz, and \$T_r\$ is the 10-90 rise time in nanoseconds. Typically \$T_r = T_f\$, but for cases when they are not we take the shorter timing.

Clock rate and signal bandwidth are not entirely independent, however:

The maximum allowable transition times are inherently dependent upon the clock rate. For example, you can't possibly have a 10MHz clock with a 10µs Tr/Tf, because the clock period at 10MHz is 100ns and there must be at least two transitions per period.

The signal bandwidth is defined by the Tr/Tf, as seen above. As such, the maximum feasible signal bandwidth that we can design for sets just how short we can make the Tr/Tf, which in turn sets the absolute maximum clock frequency we can use.

As the frequency (bandwidth) of signals travelling across a PCB increases, and the wavelength of the signal shortens to less than that of the length of the traces, transmission line effects become more and more apparent. We have to start caring about impedance matching, impedance discontinuities, wave propagation time and timing skew, crosstalk, various other signal integrity issues, and radiative EMI. This is non-trivial, and translates to increased engineering effort and costs in both the circuit design and PCB manufacturing.

In a single data rate (SDR) bus there are, at most, half as many transitions per second in the data lines than there are in the clock line. If you are already designing to a particular maximum signal bandwidth (set by the Tr/Tf of the clock) and you're looking to maximise the data rate of your bus, you can double the data rate of your data lines using DDR signalling without increasing the overall maximum signal bandwidth that you have to design around.

There are downsides to using DDR, though. The allowable timing skew between the clock signal and the data signals, and between each of the data signals themselves, is significantly reduced. This is because we must have the signal in a valid state at both the rising *and* falling edges of the clock. Additionally, DDR introduces extra complexity in the receiver.

Typically, DDR receivers work using two clocks shifted 180° out of phase, with the data line being sampled at the rising edge of each phase.

[image: A timing diagram showing DDR data being decoded using two clock phases, with the second phase synthesised by a PLL]

A phase-locked loop (PLL) or delay-locked loop (DLL) may be used to synthesise the second phase of the clock signal from the first. This may be done at the transmitter, with both phases of the clock transported on the bus, but the phase shifted clock is more commonly synthesised at the receiver. In the latter case, only `clk_p0` needs to be transmitted over the bus.

While it may be tempting to think that the second phase of the clock can simply be derived from an inverter, since clock phase 1 is indeed an inversion of clock phase 0, this is not typically feasible at high speed because of the propagation delay that an inverter would introduce.

In the above timing diagram, the data '01011000' is sent over the bus. The rising edge of clock phase 0 is used to sample the even numbered timings, and the rising edge of clock phase 1 is used to sample the odd numbered timings.

While I have shown the data split into two phases, each matching the rising edge of the corresponding clock phase, it is possible to combine the data into a single serial stream. However, this would require that the device either internally operates at twice the bus clock frequency or duplicates all of its synchronous circuitry for operation with two separate clock phases.

In some cases, having an IC internally operate at twice the bus frequency is not a problem, because the signals are only being distributed over a very small area, unlike on the PCB where the traces may be 10cm or longer.

An alternative approach is to have the bus receiver act like a 2-bit serial-in parallel-out (SIPO) shift register. A single-bit register (D flip-flop) samples the data line on the rising edge of clock phase 0. Another 2-bit register samples the data line *and* the output of the single-bit register at the rising edge of clock phase 1. This turns each sequential bit on the DDR bus into a parallel pair of bits that can be consumed at the same clock rate as the bus.

[Here's a simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgwEkwNDwaaIFDSpgBUCmwBKIQoJ59sKcLwnKwcIdCQptIJjGw1ikQgjyVsxPHjPEo26bMEobIJULdV1m3Tr26GMQoCER4kNhgJsHkMAgcXO6QLgiKhHhCqRLxAO4qfCF8CvyCkGx5cvlVxWUVLm6uGY1Q5dXixcR8ZWBu4c5VlcpNhGwAsrSaYoJ06uLKfmMT3lkzmQVa8TJ9lR6V3kK+AXpUcQlIuPLi2OklErVJly4Ys6WtF2tVhS0AHvoI9D1lPILLQDiAAMYAGwA1gB9AAOZV+TCyKGIEAgaOmYKhcPh7F+rCoVn4GRoQLBABMAIYAF2pb2SnzcNVazWKzWa905bneXLYAHtwOAuhNrNQYPBIGQzIQQmphfQAMIAGQA0rCAApwQVCEUSETipCS+Ay1Ly-bKZXqrXsIXkMCiw0ZY2wU28c3GvXkegAEV9Ul19kdBulLocGOFvoAggAVLVlIUafVUZ0S6CRiAx+Oa9hAA) showing this working in practice:

[image: Simulation schematic showing the construction]

*(note: the 200Hz clock is just for the simulation, because the sequence generator is triggered on a rising edge)*

The sequence being transmitted is 01011000 just like before. If you look at the outputs, you'll see they go to 01, then 01 again, then 10, and finally 00, before looping back around.

If you've got a parallel bus with many DDR data signals, you can think of the above example as halving the number of physical signals you require to transmit the same overall symbol rate. In this sense, DDR acts as a form of time division multiplexing.

This brings us to another conclusion: doubling the number of data lines while continuing to use SDR signalling is another effective method of doubling the data rate. The typical limitations here are IO count and physical PCB layout.

In summary, you should go through the following checklist before trying to implement DDR:

1. Am I transmitting signals over a medium (e.g. PCB) where the maximum data transfer rate is defined by signal integrity limitations?
2. Do I really need the bus itself to go faster? Is there a way to solve the problem without increasing the bus clock rate?
3. Do the physical parameters of my system (impedance matching, driver jitter, line loading, EMI, etc.) allow me to decrease Tr/Tf any further, to accommodate a higher bus clock rate?
4. Can I compensate for these physical limitations with better PCB layout or differential signalling?
5. Can I increase the width of the bus to accommodate more symbols per clock in parallel?

If the answer to all of these is no, then you might consider implementing DDR.

One case where the answer to all of these questions is invariably *"no"* is in the system memory of computers. In DDR, DDR2, DDR3, DDR4, DDR5, etc. each memory technology pushed the boundaries of what was reliable at an affordable cost point given the technology of the time. Fast operation is highly desirable, the limits of the technologies are being pushed, and the bus is already fairly wide, so it makes sense to use DDR in that case.

For lower speed circuits, there's almost never a reason to use DDR, because you're operating far below the limits of the technology you're using.

Comment: This is all based on a wrong understanding of what SDR and DDR are. Double Data *Rate* (and the then-retrospectively named SDR) are techniques for passing data across buses between ICs -hence 'rate'. They are not the names of techniques for digital logic circuit design. Downvoting accordingly, I'm afraid. Incidentally, I can't see how adding a disclaimer paragraph at the top would help, as people sometimes do, as the whole text's based on that misunderstanding.

Comment: Please provide links or citations for the graphics you copied into your answer. That is the policy for this site.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I made them.

Comment: @TonyM That's specifically my point. _Between_ ICs, DDR sometimes makes sense. _Within_ ICs it makes no sense, because the transfer rate isn't primarily limited by transition rate within the data lines. I've added an extra point to the selection criteria to clear this up.

Comment: That's not what I can see. Unfortunately, it's a very very long answer for this site for the points it's making and reads like a tutorial than an answer, so I don't think more text is the way forward. To be honest, from your comments it sounds like you've brought DDR up and are now trying to make it work in this context, which it doesn't remotely. Using both edges of the clock for general digital logic is a bad idea but the reasons are nothing to do with DDR technology.  I do think you are misunderstanding DDR and digital logic.

Comment: @TonyM The length of the answer and the appropriate level of thoroughness is _very_ much down to personal preference; someone describing a long answer as "unfortunate" is a new one to me in >10 years of StackExchange. I'm not "trying to fit" DDR to anything. Double pumped sampling is the entire point of this question. It sounds like you've made your mind up, though, so I'll leave it at that and let OP decide whether it was useful. I've got nothing more to add.

Comment: Please read the length comment for it's content, it was hard phrasing it to (a) get a good reception while (b) not understating it. But I'm proposing a reasonable point. On the rest, I'm very happy to discuss/explore it further if you want to set up a chat, there's plenty to look at. Otherwise, I'll leave it there and wish you well.